# How to restrict internet connectivity in VirtualBox?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, internet, ip

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 machine and I have just installed Windows 7 ultimate in VirtualBox.

I don't want to give internet access to that virtual machine but it must have an IP address so I can communicate with it.

Is there any relevant solution for this?
Thanking you.

Comment: In the main preferences for Virtualbox, (File > Preferences), in the network section, under the "Host-only networks" tab, click "Add". Then, In the settings for the Virtual machine, under "Adapter 1", select "Host-only adapter" - this should give you what you want.

Comment: @JonasCz-ReinstateMonica it looks like you have posted your answer in the comment section by mistake ;)